# Producing some output if an item is present in one list, not in other list

Tags: python

I have two lists of dates. I want to produce an output if a date is present, another if not. My code is:

```
main_list = ['2019-01-24', '2019-01-25', '2019-01-26', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-29', '2019-01-30']

result_list = ['2019-01-24', '2019-01-26', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-30']
```

I want to produce an output list based on the above two lists. I want to prouce an output `1` if a date of main_list is present in result_list, `0` if not.

My expected output is:

```
output_list = [1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
```

My code is:

```
output_list = [if (i=j) 1 for i,j in zip(met4_gooddays,alldates)]
```

I know this is wrong and it is inefficient approach. I would like to know if there is a dataframe approach or someother efficient?

Comment: That's not inefficient, that's a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) where you loop over the `main_list` and check if each element exists in the `result_list`

```
main_list = ['2019-01-24', '2019-01-25', '2019-01-26', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-29', '2019-01-30']

result_list = ['2019-01-24', '2019-01-26', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-30']

output_list = [1 if i in result_list else 0 for i in main_list ]
# [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
list(map(int,[x in result_list for x in main_list]))
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, use a set when performing membership checks inside a loop, this ensures your code runs in linear time rather than quadratic time.

With that out of the way, let's try something functional with `map`:

```
s = set(result_list) 

list(map(s.__contains__, main_list))                                                                                   
# [True, False, True, True, False, False, True]

# if you want a list of 0s and 1s
list(map(int, map(s.__contains__, main_list)))                                                                         
# [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

In list comprehension form, this would be

```
[int(d in s) for d in main_list]
# [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension (to avoid going to a `map` and back to a `list`):

```
output_list = [int(i in result_list) for i in main_list]

print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

It checks for every element in `main_list` whether it exists in `result_list` (of course with `int(True) ==> 1` and `int(False) ==> 0`).

Answer (score 0):

Turn `result_list` into a `set` for faster look up in the comprehension.

```
>>> rset = set(result_list)
>>> [1 if m in rset else 0 for m in main_list]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Not that it matters for such a small input, but in principle it is more efficient.

Another way, some may consider cleaner

```
>>> [int(m in rset) for m in main_list]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

This is assuming all dates are in the same format and string comparisons are a valid way to compare them. Converting to date for comparison might be more robust.